# Parallel fitting of multiple Keras Models on single GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, keras

I'm trying to fit multiple small Keras models in parallel on a single GPU. Because of reasons i need to get them out of a list and train them one step at a time. Since I was not lucky with the standard multiprocessing module i use pathos.

What I tried to do is something like this:

```py
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool as Pool
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

def multiprocess_step(self, model):
    K.set_session(sess)
    with sess.graph.as_default():
        model = step(model, sess)
        return model

def step(model, sess):
    K.set_session(sess)
    with sess.graph.as_default():
        model.fit(x=data['X_train'], y=data['y_train'],
               batch_size=batch_size
               validation_data=(data['X_test'], data['y_test']), 
               verbose=verbose,
               shuffle=True,
               initial_epoch=self.step_num - 1)
        return model

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

K.set_session(sess)
with sess.graph.as_default():
    pool = Pool(8).map
    model_list = pool(multiprocess_step, model_list)
```

but whatever I try I keep getting an error claiming that the models dont seem to be on the same graph...

`ValueError: Tensor("training/RMSprop/Variable:0", shape=(25, 352), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("RMSprop/rho/read:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).`

The exception originates in the model.fit() row so I must have done something wrong with the assignment of the session graph even though I tried to set that in every possible location?

Does anyone have experience with something similar?

Comment: Try declaring each model in its process, along with it's session.

Comment: By delaring you mean creting an entirely new model and then load the weights into it?

Comment: yes! your problem may be coming from new sessions/graphs that are created in different processes and don't have the original nodes declared outside.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the backend is set to tensorflow for the keras. you can use code and do parallel processing for multiple model invocation/ multiple model loading.

```
def model1(dir_model):
    model = os.path.join(dir_model, 'model.json')
    dir_weights = os.path.join(dir_model, 'model.h5')
    graph1 = Graph()
    with graph1.as_default():
        session1 = Session(graph=graph1, config=config)
        with session1.as_default():
            with open(model, 'r') as data:
                model_json = data.read()
            model_1 = model_from_json(model_json)
            model_1.load_weights(dir_weights)
    return model_1,gap_weights,session1,graph1

def model_2(dir_model):
    model = os.path.join(dir_model, 'model.json')
    dir_weights = os.path.join(dir_model, 'model.h5')
    graph2 = Graph()
    with graph2.as_default():
        session2 = Session(graph=graph2, config=config)
        with session2.as_default():
            with open(model, 'r') as data:
                model_json = data.read()
            model_2 = model_from_json(model_json)
            model_2.load_weights(dir_weights)
    return model_2,session2,graph2
```

and for invocation of the specific model do the following experiments.
for model 1 predict do the following

```
K.set_session(session2)
with graph2.as_default():
     img_pred[img_name] = 
patch_dict[np.argmax(np.squeeze(model_2.predict(img_invoke)))
```

and for the model 2 it follows same as

```
K.set_session(session2)
with graph2.as_default():
     img_pred[img_name] = 
patch_dict[np.argmax(np.squeeze(model_2.predict(img_invoke)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following was suggested on the [Keras issue tracker](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3287). I'm not sure about the relative merits of the approach compared to using multiprocessing.

```
in_1 = Input()
lstm_1 = LSTM(...)(in_1)
out_1 = Dense(...)(lstm_1)

in_2 = Input()
lstm_2 = LSTM(...)(in_2)
out_2 = Dense(...)(lstm_2)

model_1 = Model(input=in_1, output=out_1)
model_2 = Model(input=in_2, output=out_2)

model = Model(input = [in_1, in_2], output = [out_1, out_2])
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

model_1.predict(...)
model_2.predict(...)
```